# Call Ajax to insert query in php file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a problem with a call ajax.
I receive always an error 500, but I don't understand the problem....if is the call ajax or the php file....
This is my javascript and php code

```
$.ajax(
{                   
type: "POST",
url: 'insert_buy.php',
data: {buy: 4, sell: 2},
success: function(data) 
{
console.log(data );
},
error: function(jqXHR, exception) 
{
if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                            alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
                        } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                            alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
                        } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                            alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
                        } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                            alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
                        } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                            alert('Time out error.');
                        } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                            alert('Ajax request aborted.');
                        } else {
                            alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
                        }
                    }   
            });
```

This is the insert_buy.php

```
<?php
    $buy = $_POST['buy']; 
    $sell = $_POST['sell']; 

    $query=" INSERT INTO `buyer_seller`(`IdBuyer`, `IdSeller`) VALUES (".$buy.",".$sell.")";

      $result=mysql_query($query);
      $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
      // for first row only and suppose table having data
      echo json_encode($row);  // pass array in json_encode   
?>
```

Comment: [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) is obsolete. Do not use it. Error 500 means an error on the server, i.e. in your PHP code.

Comment: try to console.log(jqXHR.responseText) for more detail

Comment: i think  `
$result=mysql_query($query);
  $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);` is not correct way, check php fetch array manual

Comment: please require wp-load.php file into your insert_buy.php

Answer (score 0):

If this is all of your code, then you are missing to open a database connection in your `insert_buy.php`. This script is executed with no context, so you have to call `mysql_connect()` first, before calling `mysql_query()`.

Generally: If you get an Error 500 when executing a php script, look into the php error log (sometimes the apache error log) to identify the root cause of the problem.